# When was let introduced to Lisp?

Tags: lisp

Similar to [When was DEFUN added to Lisp?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13836/3722) when was `let` introduced? It seems like a fundamental feature but unless I missed something even [maclisp](https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/MIT/Moon-MACLISP_Reference_Manual-Apr_08_1974.pdf) didn't contain it.

Comment: Possibly the answer is closely related to "when was lexical scoping introduced to LISP?" - I note that the [initial Scheme paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5794/AIM-349.pdf) _doesn't_ have it ... (probably because it doesn't _need_ it as `LAMBDA` suffices).

Comment: Maclisp used `lambda` or `prog` for binding variables; `prog` was more common. (Source: empirical observations of Maclisp code—can't write much right now.) I don't know the answer to the question, though. It's something I've wondered myself. Steele and Gabriel's "Evolution of Lisp" says it was invented in Lisp Machine Lisp.

Comment: @texdr.aft - I can confirm that my _Chine Nual_ (March 1981, 3rd ed) has `let` and `let*`.

Comment: And [here they are defined](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_mitcadrWeiManualJan1979_21093856/page/n23/mode/2up) in the _first edition_ LISP Machine Manual (Jan 1979).

Comment: @davidbak would you care to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd think (ok, *I* thought) it was introduced with Scheme.  But the [initial Scheme paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5794/AIM-349.pdf) doesn't have it.  Probably because it doesn't *need* it as `LAMBDA` suffices.  (In fact, as we know due to G.L.Steele Jr., `LAMBDA` [suffices](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5790) [for](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6091) [*everything*](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5753)*!!*)

(In a comment above, @texdr.aft points to:) The paper [*Evolution of Lisp* (Steele, Jr., Gabriel, 1993)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/155360.155373), a fairly definitive exposition of LISP history by a pair of researchers who were involved in *creating it*, claims `LET` came from Lisp Machine Lisp:

> but LET—itself a macro first invented and reinvented locally at each site—was a late-comer to the MacLisp world; according to Lisp Archive, it was retroactively absorbed into PDP-10 MacLisp from Lisp-Machine Lisp in 1979 at the same time as DEFMACRO and the complex Lisp Machine DEFUN
> argument syntax.

So let's go to the source - here is the [1st edition of the *Chine Nual*](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_mitcadrWeiManualJan1979_21093856/page/n23/mode/2up) - the Lisp Machine Lisp manual - and we see here the definition of `LET` - 1979-JAN:

[image]

(For which it is explained that *of course* it is a macro that expands into a lambda.)

(By the time of the 3rd ed, 1981-MAR, they had already added `LET*`, as seen in my copy of the red *Chine Nual*.)